# iOS Run errors s Xamarin Live Player and Hanselman.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin-live-player

I created an app based off the Hanselman Forms app.  I'm trying to get it to run with the new Xamarin iOS Live Player and i'm getting runtime build errors.
To make sure it wasn't something i broke i did a fresh install of Hanselman Forms and Visual Studio 2017 Preview and connected the iPhone live player.

The build compiles fine with VS.
Trying to run the debug app with Live Player on iPhone gives the following errors.

---

The following errors were encountered when building and running your app:

• TweetStore.cs: The type or namespace name 'ITweetStore' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
• TweetStore.cs: The type or namespace name 'Tweet' does not exist in the namespace 'Hanselman.Portable' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
• LaunchTwitter.cs: The type or namespace name 'ILaunchTwitter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

### • AppDelegate.cs: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

OK

The packets have been refreshed. 
I've removed the bin/obj files to do a fresh build.
I've removed the reference, built clean, got similar errors in VS, added the reference back in and the VS build succeeds.
Android works fine.

Any ideas as to what i'm missing?

Comment: I experience the same thing with my own projects, try this samples projects from build. Those should work ok. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/build2017-future-of-mobile

Comment: Thank you.  I checked those out.  The MasterDetailForms solution builds and displays on the iOS live player.   I've posted this issue on the Xamarin forum.  Hopefully someone there can help us out.  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95825/ios-run-time-errors-type-or-namespace-name-not-found-with-xamarin-live-player-and-hanselman-forms/p1?new=1

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and is being worked on by the Xamarin folks.
Details at the following link.  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95825/ios-run-time-errors-type-or-namespace-name-not-found-with-xamarin-live-player-and-hanselman-forms/p1?new=1

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have selected a Startup Project that matches your device type (iOS or Android) and that the configuration matches that device type (eg. Debug|iPhone Simulator for iOS).